# Issue finding elements in HTML retrieved by .load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've encountered a funny quirk when trying to dynamically produce a sidebar index of hyperlinks in HTML which has been placed into a div by the `.load()` method.

The script finds the appropriate anchor tags and reproduces them in the aside, but finds them in the content which occupied the element before `.load()` updated the DOM.

Relevant JS:

```
var $result = $("#result"); // optimize!
var $aside = $("aside");
var $head = $("head");
var $title = $("title");
$.getJSON("script.php", queryObject, function(data) {
  $("#newStyle").remove(); // get rid of old specific styles
  $.each(data, function(i, row) {
    $result.load(row.html); // the database is storing a bunch of urls
    $title.text(row.title);
    if (!!row.css) { // get specific styles if they exist
      $("<link/>", {
        rel : "stylesheet",
        id : "newStyle",
        href : row.css
      }).appendTo($head);
    }
    if (!!row.js) $.getScript(row.js); // get specific scripts if they exist
  });
  var $links = $result.find("a").not(".toTop a"); // I have "back to top" things to avoid
  if ($links.length) { // better way to do this? this always returns true.
    var string = "<h2>References</h2><ul>";
    $links.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      string += "<li><a href='" + $this.attr("href") + "'>" + $this.text() + "</a></li>";
    });
    string += "</ul>";
    $aside.html(string);
  }
}).fail(errorHandle); // ain't no scrub... probably am scrub
```

This results in filling the aside with a list of anchors (that fit the description) which *were* in the page *before* the event which triggered the `$.getJSON()` and subsequent DOM update. Tried to recreate the problem in JSFiddle, but it didn't play nice with `.load()`.

Is there a way I can ensure `$links` will be an object full of fresh anchors?

Comment: Like `$.getJSON()`, `load()` is asynchronous and takes a callback parameter to run on complete, so it looks like you need to put everything from `var links...` to the end into this callback.

Comment: Your use of `$result` is a bit confusing tho - you are looping through `data` and overwriting its contents with each value. Do you mean to be appending to its existing HTML instead? (BTW `if ($links.length > 0)` is the better way to do it)

Comment: @Rhumborl in the actual full code, the object the php returns has multiple key-object pairs. The `$.each` exists because my attempts to do something like `data.key.html` have all failed, whereas running a loop on `data.key`, even if there's only one value object, just works. I've gotten it to sort of work by simply moving `var $links` down and out of the `$.getJSON`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Rhumborl, the problem is the asynchronicity of `$.load()`. It got a little gross because the order I want things listed and the way the JSON is structured from 2 database queries just don't jive well. This is the function that works:

```
function anchorSelf() {
$.getJSON("/php/loadsop.php", {"query" : $(this).attr("value")}, function(data) {
    // reset CSS from current page
    $("#newStyle").remove();
    $.each(data.sop, function(i, row) {
        // build aside heading
        id = row.sopID;
        if (row.sopID < 100) id = "0" + id;
        if (row.sopID < 10) id = "0" + id;
        string = "<h1>SOP " + row.catID + id;
        if (!!row.suffix) string += row.suffix;
        if (!!row.revision) string += " rev " + row.revision;
        string += "</h1><h2>" + row.category + "</h2>";
        $title.text(row.shortTitle);
        if (!!row.css) {
            $("<link/>", {
                rel : "stylesheet",
                id : "newStyle",
                href : row.css
            }).appendTo($head);
        }
        if (!!row.js) $.getScript(row.js);
    });
    // start the list of sops in the category
    string += "<ul>";
    $.each(data.links, function(i, row) {
        string += "<li><a class='self' value='" + row.sopID + "'>" + row.shortTitle + "</a></li>";
    });
    string += "</ul>";
    $.each(data.sop, function(i, row) {
        // load the new page
        $result.load(row.html, function() {
            // find references in the new html
            var $links = $result.find("a").not(".toTop a").not("a[name]");
            if ($links.length > 0) {
                string += "<h2>References</h2><ul>";
                $links.each(function() {
                    $this = $(this);
                    if ($this.hasClass("self")) string += "<li><a class='self' value='" + $this.attr("value") + "'>" + $this.text() + "</a></li>";
                    else string += "<li><a href='" + $this.attr("href") + "'>" + $this.text() + "</a></li>";
                });
                string += "</ul>";
            }
            $aside.html(string);
        });
    });
    $aside.html(string);
}).fail(errorHandle);
$result.on("click", "a.self", anchorSelf);
$aside.off("click", "a", catQuery).on("click", "a.self", anchorSelf);
}
```

In summary, I added another `$.each` for the first key after the `$.each` for the second key to handle the `.load` at a location in which concatenations of the `string` placeholder variable in the callback function would produce the desired result in my sidebar.